# Trying to put my text to the right side of an image, having some issues

Tags: css

```
#index .post-tnail {
position:relative;
margin:0 0 10px -4px;
}

#index .post-tnail img {
position:relative;
float:left;
display:block;
width:200px;
height:auto;
background:#1c1c1c;
border:1px solid #2a2a2a;
padding:3px;
}

#index .post-content {
margin:0 0 10px -4px;
position: relative;
}

<div class="post-tnail">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/news/1.jpg" alt="Img" title="Img" /></a>
</div>                          

<div class="post-content">
    <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

The problem is like this.

```
| [IMAGE]Text1 |
| Text2        |
| Text3        |
```

Text1 is too near to the image. There should be 15px distance between text1 and the image.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Give the `<img>` - `margin-right: 15px`. The margins and paddings on the **text** will not work properly because the img is floated element:

```
#index .post-tnail img {
    margin-right: 15px
{
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a margin-right on the image (or margin-bottom if its the space below the image that's the problem). Like this:

```
#index .post-tnail img {
position:relative;
float:left;
display:block;
width:200px;
height:auto;
background:#1c1c1c;
border:1px solid #2a2a2a;
padding:3px;
margin-right:5px;
}
```